# redeclared as different kind of symbol error

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have an .h file with the following declarations:

```
typedef SetElement (*copySetElements)(SetElement);
typedef void (*freeSetElements)(SetElement);
typedef int (*compareSetElements)(SetElement, SetElement);
```

and another .h file with the following delarations:

```
   SetElement copySetElements (SetElement element);
   void freeSetElements (SetElement element);
   int compareSetElements (SetElement element1, SetElement element2);
```

And I get the error: redeclared as different kind of symbol

in the second .h file (where I decalared the functions)

Once I change their names it dissapearrs. why?

Comment: Give the function that's a possible target for a function pointer declaration a *different* name so there is no name collision.  A simple way to do this is to append a word to the identifier that you used for the function pointer.  Like "copySetElementsFunctionPointer".  Some programmers like "fpCopySetElements".  Pick one.

Answer (score 2):

Typedefs share the same namespace as functions and global variables.

When you use the same name for two different things, the compiler wouldn't know which one you mean. So it gives an error instead.